# Need to stack subpages on home page of Google Sites — how?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites

*This is a rephrasing of my original question **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516983/google-sites-trying-to-script-announcements-page-on-steroids**:*

I've been looking into ways to make subpages of a parent page appear in a grid like "articles" on the home page of my Google Site — like on a Joomla home page and *almost* like a standard "Announcements" template, **except**:

- The articles should appear in a configurable order, **not** chronologically (or alphabetically).
- The first two articles should be displayed full-width and the ones beneath in two columns.
- All articles will contain one or more images, and at least the first one should be displayed.
- The timestamp and author of each subpage/article shouldn't be displayed.

At the moment I don't care if everything except the ordering is hardcoded, but ideally there should be a place to input prefs like the number of articles displayed, image size, snippet length, css styling etc.

My progress so far:

- I tried using an iframe with an outside-hosted Javascript (using *google.feeds.Feed*) that pulls the RSS feed from the "Announcements" template, but I can't configure the order of the articles. One possibility would be to have a number at the beginning of every subpage title and parse it, but it's going to mess up with time and the number would also be visible on the standalone article page. Or could the number be hidden with Javascript?
- I tried making a spreadsheet with a row for each article with columns "OrderId", "Title", "Content", "Image" and process and format the data with a Google App Script (using *createHTML* and *createImage*), but **a)** there doesn't seem to be a way to get a spreadsheet image to show up inside the webapp and **b)** these articles are not "real" pages that can be linked to easily on the menus.

This feature would be super-useful for lots of sites, and to me it just seems odd that it isn't a standard gadget (edit: **or template**). Ideas, anyone?

Comment: _This is a rephrasing of my original question..._ So you should just edit the original question to make it clearer.

Comment: You can ask for enhancement at the [google apps script issues](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Comment: Mogsdad, I considered editing the question — but the title would now be misleading as I originally thought the solution would have something to do with the "Announcements" template. Actually what I'm asking for is probably impossible to achieve right now within the scope of tools that Google has given us, **without** ugly number indexing of the page titles.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I've now posted the issue here: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2378

Comment: You can edit the title as well.

Comment: Thanks George, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is helpful, but I wanted something similar and used the RSS XML announcements feed within a Google Gadget embedded into my sites page
Example gadget / site:
http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/105840169337292240573/CBC_news_v3_1.xml
http://www.cambridgebridgeclub.org

It is badly written, messy and I'm sure someone could do better than me, but it seems to work fairly reliably.  The xml seems to have all the necessary data to be able to chop up articles, and I seem to remember it has image urls as well, so can play with them (although not implemented in my gadget).

Apologies if I am missing the point.  I agree with your feature request - it would be great not to have to get so low-level to implement stuff like this in sites....

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The gadget in your link looks a bit like one by a Danish guy I found and started to adapt (that one used an old API). With your code, one can at least specify which article shows up first with `<UserPref name="first_index" display_name="Index of first entry to show:" default_value="0"/>` but when there's a new entry in the feed, all the others get pushed down one position and you have to adjust the number...right?

Comment: I suppose I'd go the RSS way (at least until there was a better solution) if only I could order the articles like a nav menu can be ordered. By the way...can a navigation block be accessed by app script?

Comment: Yeah, new items added push down the feed (which is obviously what I wanted).  I'm not sure who will be writing your articles but one idea might be to hide something in the articles text/html to uniquely id them if you want them to be 'sticky' etc. On sites, you can have several different Announcements streams, so you could have one for 'static' items?  Beyond that I guess using spreadsheets/scriptdb and a script to keep track of pages.  I thought announcements pages were the same as other sites pages ie could use the Sites service in GAS to get pages (and details)?

Comment: Well, doing a `getAllDescendants()` on an Announcements-templated page (or any page with subpages) will retrieve the pages as an object. Problem is, it's still ordered by last posts or updates AND when you do a `createHTML()` to output the content of the pages, Google for the time being strips out the `<IMG>` tags (**even those referring to images uploaded directly to the site!?**). Maybe parsing each page object and doing a `createImage()` to substitute each `<IMG>` tag will do the trick, but it seems really stilted and too much processing to just put out this simple thingy.

Comment: I had a look at the standard "Recent posts" gadget too, and it would probably only need a few lines of additional code: custom ordering, timestamp option, full/half width grid. Where's the source code of this? Can a standard Google gadget be disassembled somehow?

Comment: OK, maybe there's a workable solution until(?) Google decides to improve the gadget: 

— Subpages are added as posts under a parent Announcements templated page. 

— An app script in a spreadsheet is used to list the subpages (only ID and Title) in a UiApp, with a dropdown selector for the ordering (1-8).

— The UiApp updates the spreadsheet's column "Order" on submit. 

— The column "Order" and "ID" is published as CSV.

— The XML gadget (similar to the one used on http://www.cambridgebridgeclub.org) imports the CSV as well as the RSS feed and orders the articles.